# Username appearing in django migrations over custom User model with no username

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

I have written a custom User model, with no username. Still it appears in migrations as primary key and throws unique constraint error while adding new user.

Here is my User Model Manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
  def create_user(self, password,email=None, phone=None, **extra_fields):
    if not email and not phone:
        raise ValueError("User must have an email address or phone number")

    if email:
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,**extra_fields)
    elif phone:
        user = self.model(phone=phone,**extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user

  def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True,
        is_superuser=True,
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

Here is my User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True,
                          verbose_name='email address',
                          max_length=255,
                          null=True
                          )
  phone = models.CharField(unique=True,
                        verbose_name='phone number',
                        max_length=10,
                        null=True
                        )

  name = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True)
  profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

  objects = UserManager()


  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.email)

  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    return True

  def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    return True
```

Now,The migrrations:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
        name='User',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
            ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
            ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
            ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='first name')),
            ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
            ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
            ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')),
            ('phone', models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name='phone number')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)),
            ('profile_pic', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='')),
            ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('is_admin', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
            ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
        ],
```

Wow,That was unexpected.Now since there is username here, which in unique constraint. I cannot add more than 1 user with blank username, as I provide email or phone only.

Answer (score 1):

You did not written custom User without username as AbstractUser does implement a fully featured User model with admin-compliant permissions.  As [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user):

> AbstractUser provides the full implementation of the default User as
> an abstract model.

You should extend AbstractBaseUser instead as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)